# Problems with MySQL bidirectional relationship and mirrored foreign keys 

Tags: mysql, replication, bidirectional

i have to create two tables with a bidirectional relationship, as in the figure given below. 
[image]
But it always gives an error. I am using the following query for creating the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rpt_operation` (
  `op_id` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `component` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `ideal_time` time NOT NULL,
  `handling_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`op_id`),

  INDEX (component),
  FOREIGN KEY (component)
  REFERENCES rpt_component(comp_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rpt_component` (
  `comp_id` int(45) NOT NULL,
  `lot_code` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `lot_color` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `drawing_num` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `revision_num` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `operation` int(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comp_id`),

  INDEX (operation),
  FOREIGN KEY (operation)
  REFERENCES rpt_operation(op_id)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The error appear in the line `component int(45) NOT NULL` of rpt_operation table.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: firstly, this is most likely due to the order of commands, you might create both tables first and then set the indexes on them. Anyway, a "bidirectional" relation, is somtimes a hint to better but both tables into one larger table (cant have a row in rpt_operation without one in rpt_component) as I can't see a break in normalization by doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table structure is impossible. You can't insert any records into `rpt_operation` because there are no records in `rpt_component` for the `component` foreign key, and you can't insert any records into `rpt_component` because there are no records in `rpt_operation` for the `operation` foreign key.

If you make one or both of those fields nullable, then the table structure is still recursive, so you have to add one of the foreign keys manually, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE rpt_operation
  ADD CONSTRAINT
  FOREIGN KEY (component)
  REFERENCES rpt_component(comp_id);
```

Comment: The cyclic dependency could be solved in other DBMS by using deferred constraints though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a linking-table to resolve this problem. This is not a viable solution and requires workarounds.